# Sumifs with muitiple criteria based on a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am facing a problem with excel. I know we can make a SUMIF using multiple values as criteria, but how can we do this when using SUMIFS ?

What I mean is ( as you can see at the exampled picture ):

- I need to get the sum os values when Feature1 is either (a or b) and Feature2 is (m or n)
- The features need to be setted by Range (in the example ColumnE for feature1 and ColumnF for feature2), not manually

The answer should be 2

[image: Image Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *(using your {a,b,m,n} filter as an example)*:

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A5,E2:E5,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B5,F2:F5,0)))
```

Or, in case the amount in the **val** column might not always be one (1):

```
=SUM((ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A5,E2:E5,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B5,F2:F5,0)))*C2:C5)
```

[image]

Comment: Man, it looks like its working perfectly. I will try in my real world scenario and comeback for mark as closed

Answer (score 3):

You can try to `SUM` an array search for `a` or `b` as a constant requirement

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,{"a","b"},B:B,F2))
```

Comment: It works when using only one condition to the feature2. I tried 

=SUM(SUMIFS(C:C;A:A;{"a";"b"};B:B;{"m";"n"}))

Which should have returned me "3" but its resulting "2"

Comment: Well that’s different than your question. Try showing more examples so we can see the pattern and having something to test against

Comment: Sorry, have just eddited the question

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about SUMIFS but you can use an OR condition with SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A2:A5="a")+(A2:A5="b"))*(B2:B5="n"))
```